# Creating Custom Forms for Outlook 2010

Tags: custom-form, outlook

I am given a task to create custom forms for Outlook 2010. I need to learn about Adding and Populating Custom Controls like dropdowns. I am a fresher in Sharepoint and the first task i got is as stated above.

Can anyone guide me how to go about it?I am not asking for Readymade work . I would like any related tutorials or suggestion as to how to proceed with the task.

Kindly guide me for the same.Thank You in advance.

Error to the Solution Deepu provided.

[image]

The Error above was because the form was on my system. I published it on a sharepoint site and it works fine there, but i want a custom form in Outlook to be published on Exchange server (Outlook clients accessing the Exchange server using MAPI or RPC/HTTPS). How do i go about it?

I created a custom form using http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10things/10-easy-steps-to-customizing-an-outlook-2010-form/2635 and when i mail the form to the recipient, the template used in the begining (e.g Meeting) is sent to the recepient and the Custom form created has to be viewed seperately(which makes no sense). Well, I know this is totally confusing. In short the thing is Custom forms in Outlook i am not able to Publish in Exchange server and also i want to know proper way to create a custom outlook form.

My actual requirement is a a user should use the custom form for Leave Request.

Comment: we cant read the error message on that screenshot. Could you enlarge it or paste it in as text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom forms for Outlook 2010 using SharePoint 2010? I think you need to customize forms in Outlook by integrating InfoPath forms. This will help you to communicate with SharePoint too. InfoPath forms help you to submit or receive data from and to SharePoint sites. These forms can be incorporated into Outlook. Please view these blogs for more info -

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tudort/archive/2006/02/22/536800.aspx

http://www.infopathdev.com/blogs/mel_balsamo/archive/2009/05/19/using-e-mail-forms-to-communicate-with-external-users.aspx

Comment: Hi Deepu i tried to do the infopath stuff bt when i mail it to a user on a different system, that particular person is not able to open and access the infopath form. It works fine only on my machine. Please refer the image posted in the question

Answer (score 0):

For a normal form, it sounds like you didn't just add System.Windows.Forms as a reference, create the object then show it eg.

Form myFrm= new System.Windows.Forms.Form();

myFrm.Show();

Answer (score 0):

I know this may sound silly, but I did the same thing, but found the form was there, I just had to click 'Page 2' on the ribbon - since I created the form on page 2 and the first page is just the actual message.  I hope your problem is fixed that easily.